# Adding an editable field to a custom block module

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a custom module that registers a 'block' and echoes some HTML content.

I want to make this customisable to admin users, which means enabling 'Configure' for the block: with one textfield, and a drop down when you can select a node of a specific type.

How do I go about starting this:
A) Enabling 'Configure' for the block
B) Choosing/Coding Fields that store variables, seen when you click 'Configure'
C) Echo the variables in the block module code

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check [the bean module](http://drupal.org/project/bean)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [block example module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7) should show what you want

Comment: ah thanks @Jeremy-French I will look at this and try and "master" the block!